# Arch Linux on Pi4 double display

Tags: linux, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, qt, xrandr

I'm trying to build a Qt double display Application on Raspberry Pi4 with Arch linux.

But my Rasp cannot find the two HDMI displays.

" [root@trolly home]#
xrandr Can't open display "

How can i solve it? How can i say to Arch that there are two displays and the first Qt window needs to be displayed on the first HDMI and the second one on the second HDMI?

Thanks

Comment: You have already asked that and got an answer.

Comment: You either need to run a window manager system or use an interface system that does not require one. You might be able to use [eglfs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html) but how to use *that* would be off topic here. Only the part where you need to install and/or set up a window manager is on topic here, programming is not.

Comment: If you already have an answer to this question, please do not repost it.

Comment: He has asked this and got an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086303/arch-linux-on-pi4-dobule-display

Comment: I don’t see any answer on Stack Overflow. // Please clarify the details of your Qt application. Does it run directly using the framebuffer/DRM device? Or are you first running an X server that then starts your application as its only client?